# Depict Adress Resolution Protocol using Mirobits

Tags: communication, homework, microbit

My school assignment says

> In this task you will implement a simple version of Address Resolution Protocol (ARP). A button press on one micro will send a request to the other micro for its “MAC” address. The micro should respond with its IP number and “MAC address” which you add to a table. The IP number will be a string which represents an IP address, eg “192.168.1.2” and the MAC address is a string in the standard MAC address format. Since neither the IP and MAC address are real, you will need to hard wire these into the response code. 
>   Alternatively, instead of the MAC address, you should do some research on how to find the unique identifier from your micro:bit, and use that.
>   The device that sends the ARP request should display the response, i.e. IP and “MAC” address ofthe receiver.

I don't want any code that I want to figure out myself, I just wanted to know the interpretation in plain language that what exactly do I need to code.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. I would think the task is quite clear on what you need to do: "implement a simple version of Address Resolution Protocol (ARP)". There isn't really anything we can help with. If you are struggling understanding the task, you should be asking your teacher.

Comment: I'm removing all the text irrelevant to the technical content of your post – but that doesn't give the text the property of **actually asking a question**! You *have to* ask a question here.

Comment: okay thanks guys @t

Comment: By the way: in development, the hard problem is almost never writing the code, it's knowing what to code. And that's exactly what you're asked to work on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from [The micro:bit Software Ecosystem](https://tech.microbit.org/software/#microbit-low-level-cc-software-stack):

*Typically, a program is written on the host computer and then transferred to the micro:bit over USB. There are actually two chips on the micro:bit, one that is running software entirely to facilitate the flashing (the KL26Z) and one that actually runs the user’s code (the nRF51822).*

So your user program is executed on the NXP nRF51822. This is a radio module used to make wireless connections with devices using the 2.4GHz ISM radio band. Each of the NXP nRF51822 radios should have a unique address. These addresses, previously known as a MAC (Media Access Control) address now called EUI (Extended Unique Identifiers) are  assigned by the IEEE Registration Authority.

Your assignment appears to be to create programs for two micro:bit devices. One as a requester, the second a responder. The requester sends a message to ask for the IP and EUI of the other device. The responder answers with the an IP address and a EUI address you have hard coded. Then you are to revise your code to discover the unique address embedded in the responders micro:bit and supply that in place of the hard coded one.